# How to specify allowed column values in orgmode tables?

Tags: org-mode

I have a table in org-mode:

```
  | Task                        | Status      | Note |
  |-----------------------------+-------------+------|
  | Prepare environment         | Done        |      |
  | Write a hello world example | In Progress |      |
  | Package it                  | TODO        |      |
```

Is there any way to force Status Column to limit on [Done, In Progress, TODO] values?

Comment: Not with what Org mode provides out of the box: it's just text. Any such restrictions would have to be superimposed somehow: probably the easiest thing to do would be an `org-lint`-like function that checks and complains about violations, but which would be specific to your requirements (`org-lint` complains about generic violations).

Comment: Oh! All right, thank you @NickD ;)